# How to print the input on page, onClick under the textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i wonder how could i print the value which i input in textfield.
This is my code, all fine, but instead of console.log() i would like to have the inputed value printed on screen under the textfield;

```
import { useRef } from "react";
function About() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const naglowek = "Hello";
  function clickHandler() {
    alert("Clicked");
  }
  function handleClick() {
    console.log(inputRef.current.value); // I want this to be printed on page under the input textfield
    document.getElementById("textfield1").value = "";
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{naglowek}</h1>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Kliknij</button>
      <input id="textfield1" type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <input type="button" value="tekst" onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `useRef` at all. Just create a local state which will track input's value.

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState();
const [isValueShown, showValue] = useState(false);
```

Add `onChange` to input:

```
<input id="textfield1" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
{isValueShown && <label for="textfield1">{currentValue}</label>}
```

handleChange:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCurrentValue(e.target.value)
};
```

Show it:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    showValue(true);
}
```

Comment: But i would like it to be printed on page, not in console

Answer (score 0):

useRef() doesn't trigger a re-render it is used to preserve the value . An ideal useCase for useRef() will be to get the underlying dom node . so that we can access the dom node and modify its properties. What you need here is a controlled component .

The reason we are using `useState` hook here is to trigger a re-render so that the UI is in sync with the Component state. And its recommended to have the value in state which change over a period of time either by some sideEffect like API Call or use Interaction like in this case .

```
import { useState } from "react";
function About() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [ showValue, setShowValue ] = useState(false);
 
  function clickHandler() {
    alert("Clicked");
  }

  function handleClick() {
   setShowValue(currentShowValue => !currentShowValue)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{naglowek}</h1>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Kliknij</button>
      <input id="textfield1" value={value} type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value) }/>
      <input type="button" value="tekst" onClick={handleClick} />
      <p>The value gets rendered as you type: {value}</p>
      {showValue && <p> The value gets rendered onClick: {value}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

**Refer**

[Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function About() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [showValue, setShowValue] = useState(false);
  const naglowek = "Hello";
  let inputField;

  function clickHandler() {
    alert("Clicked");
  }

  //  Show the value on click
  function handleClick() {
    setShowValue(true);
  }

  // Store & Update the value on change
  function handleChange(event) {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{naglowek}</h1>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Kliknij</button>
      <input id="textfield1" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      {showValue && text}
      <input type="button" value="tekst" onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-smoke-4wjh1aa